# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//input[contains(@id,

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Ao utilizar o codigo:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_id("//input[contains(@id,'seq')]")
```

Recebo a mensagem de erro:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//input[contains(@id,'seq')]"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/rc01/appdata/local/temp/tmp_mrf3t/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///c:/users/rc01/appdata/local/temp/tmp_mrf3t/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta recebeu votos negativos porquê você só mostrou um erro que acontece na sua máquina - não é possível reproduzi-lo nem verificar porque ele ocorre a partir das informações que você forneceu. Eu uso selenium aqui e funciona perfeitamente, o problema está no elemento  que você está tentando localizar. Veja aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve como fazer boas perguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro significa que, no momento em que essa linha de código está executando, a página não contém nenhum elemento que bate com os critérios (elemento `<input>` com atributo `id` valendo `'seq'`).

Uma causa comum para esse problema é que as páginas modernas não carregam de uma vez - elas carregam uma estrutura mínima e criam o restante dos elementos dinamicamente via execução de código javascript.

Talvez a página que você está usando ainda não terminou de executar a parte do código que cria o elemento que você quer.

A solução nesses casos é esperar a página carregar - seja usando `time.sleep()` ou alguma das [funções de espera do `selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: Eu testei sua ideia no código, porém o erro persiste.

Comment: @alexjosesilva O erro é absoluto e definitivo - **o elemento não existe**. Com as informações que você passou é só isso que posso oferecer.

Comment: Grato pela colaboração. Realmente:  o elemento não existia na url informada na busca.